# How do I delete files attached with media entity?

Tags: 8, media

**Background:**

drupal 8.4.2

custom media solution

**Issue**

I can not delete files permanently which created as media entity.

**Reproduce**

1. Created an image media entity.
2. `/admin/content/files` claims `status permanent` and `used in 2` places.
3. After deleting newly created media entity from UI `/admin/content/media`.
4. `/admin/content/files` says `status permanent` and `used in 1` places.

Even cron run after 6 hours (as described in file settings) file still exist on the server.

Is there any safest or best way to delete those unused file permanently?

Comment: Does it exist in an entity revision somewhere? Was the media entity deleted?

Comment: @kevin Yes i confirm media entity deleted. Though it works before drupal core 8.4 .* release. As unused files status changed to temporary and used in 0 places and after cron run 6 hours it delete the file. After 8.4.* default file setting of make_unused_managed_files_temporary set to false.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete old versions of entities (articles etc.) where you used the files for the files to get the "used in 0 places" under /admin/content/files. After that status should be changed to temporary with option make_unused_managed_files_temporary set to true.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/2891902